# How to install dblib PDO driver for PHP on Red Hat?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, driver

HI Techies!

I was using dblib PDO driver to connect to MS-SQL on Ubuntu.

Everything was working fine.

When I deployed my code on stage server, environment was different.

Stage server is running on Red Hat and dblib driver is not installed over there.

Can anyone please tell me how to install dblib PDO driver for PHP on Red Hat?

Many Thanks.

Comment: This seems like more a serverfault question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `PDO_DBLIB` is [a PECL package](http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_DBLIB).  You should just need to install that package.  This will require some development bundles and the relevant libraries, as well as a compiler.